In HTML, is there a way to prevent the &flat; character from shifting down?
I'm trying to write a simple HTML page to output music chords.  I display randomly generated chords to practice chord changes (like using flashcards).
When I output a chord containing a "flat" symbol, the whole chord appears to jump down -- it increases the vertical height of the enclosing <div> and appears at the bottom. The  Other chords (with a "sharp" or without) appear as expected.
JSFiddle to demonstrate:  https://jsfiddle.net/blatwell9/qjfcLtdv/3/
Is there a way to prevent the shift down from happening?
Shift down example
The code to demonstrate the effect.  Note the effect when the backgrounds of the <div> and the chord <span> are displayed:


      function showChord() {
          
          
          document.getElementById("chord").innerHTML = chordList[chordIndex];
          document.getElementById("chordWithLineHeight").innerHTML =          chordList[chordIndex];
          
          chordIndex++;
          if (chordIndex > chordList.length -1) chordIndex = 0;
          
          setTimeout(showChord, 1500);
        }
        
        let chordIndex = 0;
        let chordList = ["&sharp;","&flat;"];
        showChord();
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        body {font-family: sans-serif;}
        
        
      .chord-div {font-size: 3em; background: lightgreen; margin: .1em; }
        
      #chord {background: lightblue; 
            border: 1px blue solid;}
            
        #chordWithLineHeight {background: lightblue; 
            border: 1px blue solid; 
            line-height: 1}
      <h3> No line-height set </h3>
      <div class="chord-div">
        <span id="chord"></span>
      </div>
      
      <h3> With line-height set </h3>
      <div class="chord-div">
        <span id="chordWithLineHeight"></span>
      </div>




can you post screenshot of you mean "jump down"?

I'm not seeing any issues with the code you've presented.

The flat character is being drawn from a different font than the other characters. That font has different font metrics causing the misalignment.

@Alohci I think you're correct. The flat character (and others) cause the "jump down" must have different font metrics.  Setting line-height seems to correct the problem.

@blatwell9 You have the default font of sans-serif assigned to <body> everything within it is inheriting that simple font. I have removed the "Opus" font and replaced it with sans-serif in my answer. There's no change. It is not the font. Moreover, a line-height of 1 is OK as long as your letters stay on one line and not wrap to the next line. Default line-height that browsers employ is 1.2 (0.2 is the space above (0.1) and below (0.1) inline/inline-block tags).

@zer00ne I changed my code to demonstrate the jump down I'm seeing.  I just used float in the original because I didn't know what I was doing ;-).  The new code shows that when you display a flat by itself, it appears lower than a sharp and shows space added between the top of the flat box and the top of the div.  It seems to jump down.  line-height seems to remove the effect.  Any idea what is making the jump happen?

I see, I've updated my answer, happy coding.

Update
Sans-serif Typeface
Op has pointed out that there's still a misalignment after my solution. So the original code presented by OP had float: left in which I proved to be one of the problems. In my solution I have font-family: "Opus" because it's used specifically for sheet music. So I assumed that was fixed, unfortunately, it turns out that font-family: sans-serif is buggy and there's a misalignment with ♭. In conclusion, do not use float unless you intend to wrap text around an <img> and don't use sans-serif, use "Opus", or "Helsinki XXL", or "Segoe UI" typeface. See Example A for the float issue and Example B for font issue.
Float Issue
Instead of wasting time explaining why not to use float see this post. The example has two <section>s:

The first <section> contains only inline elements (ex. <span>, <mark>, <strong>, etc.). They naturally sit next to each other.

The second <section> contains block elements (ex. <div>, <p>, <section>, etc.). They naturally take up the whole line they sit in so they stack one on top off the other. float is supposed to arrange them inline.


As you can see the floating <div>s are cock-eyed and the ♭ symbol has nothing to do with it. Just use inline elements, flexbox or grid layouts.
Example A


@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/opus');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  3ch/1.2 "Opus" "sans-serif";
}

mark {
  margin: 0.1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: lightgreen;
}

div {
  float: left;
}
<section>
  <mark>A&sharp;</mark>
  <mark>A&#119082;</mark>
  <mark>A&flat;</mark>
  <mark>A&#119083;</mark>
  <mark>A&natur;</mark>
</section>

<section>
  <div>
    <mark>A&sharp;</mark>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mark>A&#119082;</mark>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mark>A&flat;</mark>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mark>A&#119083;</mark>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mark>A&natur;</mark>
  </div>
</section>



Example B


const chords = ["&flat;", "&sharp;", "A&flat;", "A&sharp;", "A&sharp;A&flat;", "A&natur;A&#119083;A&#119082;"];

let count = cycle(chords.length);

const showChords = (array, selector) => {
  const tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const i = count.next().value;
  if (i === 0) tags.forEach(t => t.innerHTML = "");
  tags.forEach(t => t.innerHTML += `<mark>${array[i]}</mark>`);
  setTimeout(() => showChords(array, selector), 1500);
};

function* cycle(N) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    ++i;
    i = i > (N - 1) ? 0 : i;
    yield i;
  }
}

showChords(chords, "p");
:root {
  font: 2ch/normal "Segoe UI"
}

p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: lightgreen;
}

mark {
  padding: 0 .1em;
  outline: 1px blue solid;
  background: lightblue;
}

p:nth-of-type(2) {
  line-height: 1;
}

p:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p:nth-of-type(4) {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
  
<main>
  <h3>line-height: 1.2 (default) font-family: "Segoe UI"</h3>
  <p></p>

  <h3>line-height: 1; font-family: "Segoe UI"</h3>
  <p></p>

  <h3>line-height: 1.2; font-family: sans-serif</h3>
  <p></p>
  
  <h3>line-height: 1; font-family: sans-serif</h3>
  <p></p>
</main>




Very enlightening.  I was using old documentation and didn't know about the inline elements.  I will use those in the future (and use more modern methods than float).  And get some up to date documentation.

Your new example demonstrates the problem with sans-serif.  Switching fonts seems like an optimal solution in this case.  Thanks for getting to the bottom of the problem.

You need to define line-height. In this case 1 works.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.chord-div {
  font-size: 3em;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: .1em;
  float: left
}

#sharp {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  line-height: 1;
}

#flat {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  line-height: 1;
}
<div class="chord-div">
  <span id="sharp">A&sharp;</span>
</div>
<div class="chord-div">
  <span id="flat">A&flat;</span>
</div>




line-height fixes the problem.  Thanks..  Can anyone account for why the flat character causes the shift down?

@blatwell9 it's not the ♭ making that misalignment, see my answer
